# How to use Intents with MSWord

Tags: java, android, android-intent, ms-word

I am trying to edit an MSWord document from my app.
I decided to use an Intent to do this but MSWord can't seem to locate the document to edit.   I'm not sure if I'm not correctly defining the location of the document, or if I'm not passing the uri correctly.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_EDIT);
file = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+"/mydoc.doc";
Uri uri = Uri.parse(file);
intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/msword");
activity.startActivityForResult(intent, MSWORD);
```

The result I get is that MSWord launches and I get an error message:

"Can't open file"
"Try saving the file on the device and then opening it."

Documentation on MSWord and Intents seems to be very sparse!

Answer (score 0):

At long last have found it - here for other frustrated developers!

```
    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"Documents/101131new.docx");
    Uri path = Uri.fromFile(file);
    Intent objIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    objIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    objIntent.setDataAndType(path,"application/msword");
    activity.startActivity(objIntent);
```

This allows you to work on the local file in the /Documents directory.

Answer (score 0):

Please try below:

```
    /**
     * @param fileRelativePath should be relative to SDCard 
     */
    private void launchMSWorldToOpenDoc(String fileRelativePath) {
        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), fileRelativePath);
        Uri path = Uri.fromFile(file);
        Intent msIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_EDIT);
        msIntent .setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        msIntent .setDataAndType(path,"application/msword");
        activity.startActivity(msIntent);
    }
```

Comment: That's great thanks seems to work well for local files

Comment: What I ideally want to do is access files on OneDrive - but they are not accessed as relative to SD card.  
Provided I am logged in to OneDrive, how can I specifly the location of a file on OneDrive?

Comment: WIll need to check, if we can ask MSword to open files from some other cloud, as that cloud will also ask for credentials, and even if credentials are not required, we would need to create some File URI with that OneDrive file url.